# Will an SSR work with mains voltage less than 240V? Which datasheet parameter mentions this?

Tags: solid-state-relay

I am planning to use an SSR in the secondary of a step down transformer to control a heater. My question is what parameter should I check out in the datasheet of the SSR to ensure that the SSR will operate at input voltages less than 240V?

For reference I linking the [datasheet](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=29667397725190437757&t=2966739772519043775758444) from Schneider. It does not talk about any "input voltage". Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Unless something is wrong on my end, that link does not go to the datasheet but to a list of products. Please link to a specific product so we can all discuss exactly the same thing.

Comment: I have changed the link of the datasheet to a public uploading site with the specific datasheet in question

Comment: it still doesn't work.

Comment: Now it should work

Comment: Now the link leads to a site that requires viewers to create an account.  That is not acceptable to me. I expect many others will feel the same. I always use an uploading site that has no strings attached even when I am offering free assistance and asking for nothing.

Comment: Um.. the link leads to tinyurl and there is no need to create an account to download from there

Comment: I think you are correct about tinyurl, but tinyupload is not the same. Engineering is all about attention to detail.

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=29667397725190437757&t=2966739772519043775733378

Comment: any link has got to go to **the datasheet**, not a site from where you start searching for it.

Answer (score 1):

The link is a "product selector" table. It lists input voltage ranges, that are actually control signal voltage ranges. It also lists output voltage ranges and current values that are the ranges for switched voltages and maximum switched currents.

Pick a relay that has an "output" voltage range that contains the secondary voltage of your transformer and a current that is equal to or preferably, a little greater than your  load current requirement.

The selected SSR also needs to have an input voltage range that contains the control signal that you want to use.

Then look at the individual spec sheet detail to make sure there is nothing else that you need to be concerned about.

Comment: Ok .. so I guess I have to look out for "output voltage". I was confused because SSR will just switch whatever "mains voltage" is fed.

Comment: It will switch whatever mains voltage is fed within limits. The output voltage range states those limits.

Answer (score 0):

For the Zelio Datasheet you presented, it says right in the title it's output voltage range is 24-280v AC.
The voltage drop parameter tells you it won't work at below 1.6v, and you have to be aware that you always drop this level of voltage from your working voltage. It also allows you to calculate the power dissipation with your load current.